# Can I connect to a DALI network as a master node using an Arduino?

Tags: can-bus, modbus, home-automation, automatization

I have googled a lot, and mostly every website you can link me I have already explored, some are outdated and don't work, others aren't clear in their documentation, and use equipment too expensive to run the risk of buying it and it not working.

https://github.com/edinburghhacklab/dali

https://github.com/sde1000/python-dali

https://github.com/krzychb/DimSwitch/blob/master/extras/pictures/PHILIPS-HF-REGULATOR-TOUCH-a-DALI%2018-58w-T8-%201-a-2-LAMPS.pdf

http://microcontrollershop.com/product_info.php?products_id=5384

Moreover, like any free protocol, you have to pay to access the DALI standard.

What can I do to control a network of connected DALI dimmable ballasts?

Answer (score 1):

I have made a simple DALI controller with Arduino Nano. Maybe it will be useful for you. Look here: [Simple DALI Controller](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/NabiyevTR/simple-dali-controller-506e44)

Comment: This is [almost] a [link only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Links tend to die over time. If you could expand your answer with a summary of the content of the link then that would be very helpful.

Comment: This tutorial is poetry! Amazing! Thanks! Is there a way to have it in PDF or any other offline mean (without the videos for ex.). This should be eternalized!

Comment: Hi, can you confirm that these resistors values are correct? How can you drop 12V to those voltages using that resistors? http://prntscr.com/e4guvx

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was a mistake. I have corrected. You need 2,2 and 3,3 kOhm resistors.

Comment: [DOCX version of tutorial](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8tBX6Vum7OXZGdESVd6SDVkZ00)